# Why is RotationTransform 100x slower than manually specifying the transformation?

Tags: plotting, functions, performance-tuning, rotation

I'm plotting an implicit surface using `RegionPlot3D`. I have two descriptions of the surface which I believe are (or should be) conceptually and functionally identical, but in fact the speed at which they are rendered by `RegionPlot3D` differs by *two orders of magnitude*.

```
-c <= f @@ (RotationTransform[x/32, {1, 0, 0}]@{x, y, z}) <= c

-c <= f[x, y Cos[x/32] - z Sin[x/32], z Cos[x/32] + y Sin[x/32]] <= c
```

Otherwise identical `RegionPlot3D` calls render the first version *one hundred times more slowly* than the second. Why should this be the case?

Comment: Do you place `-c <= f @@ (RotationTransform[x/32, {1, 0, 0}]@{x, y, z}) <= c` directly into `RegionPlot3D`? If so, modify it to `-c <= f @@ (RotationTransform[x/32, {1, 0, 0}]@{x, y, z}) <= c//Evaluate`

Comment: That seemed to fix the problem. Why does that work, and is there something in the official documentation I missed that should have lead me to trying this?

Comment: `RotationTransform` is indeed very slow. `Evaluate` guarantees that it is evaluated only once. The resulting expressions `f[x, y Cos[x/32] - z Sin[x/32], z Cos[x/32] + y Sin[x/32]]` is sufficiently simple so that `RegionPlot3D` can handle it efficiently.